# Mongoose/TypeScript $addToSet, $push and $pull errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function which suscribes a "userId" to a threadId like following:

```js
 suscribeToThread: async (threadId: IThread["_id"], userId: IUser["_id"]) => {
    return await threadModel.updateOne(
      { _id: threadId },
      { $addToSet: { suscribers: userId } }
    );
},
```

To which I get the following error:

```
Type '{ suscribers: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ readonly [x: string]: any; readonly [x: number]: any; } & NotAcceptedFields<_AllowStringsForIds<LeanDocument<any>>, readonly any[]> & { readonly [key: string]: any; } & { readonly id?: any; ... 4 more ...; readonly replies?: string | AddToSetOperators<...>; } & NotAcceptedFields<...>'.
  Type '{ suscribers: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NotAcceptedFields<_AllowStringsForIds<LeanDocument<any>>, readonly any[]>'.
    Property 'suscribers' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

This error only happens with $addToSet, $push and $pull operators.

Here is the model/interface for Thread Model

```
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from "mongoose";
import { IComment } from "../comment/commentModel";
import { IUser } from "../user/userModel";

export interface IThread extends Document {
  _id: string;
  title: string;
  timestamp: number;
  author: IUser["_id"];
  content: string;
  locked: boolean;
  sticky: boolean;
  likedBy: Array<IUser["_id"]>;
  dislikedBy: Array<IUser["_id"]>;
  viewedBy: Array<IUser["_id"]>;
  suscribers: Array<IUser["_id"]>;
  replies: Array<IComment["_id"]>;
}

const ThreadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  content: String,
  locked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  sticky: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  likedBy: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", default: [] }],
  dislikedBy: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", default: [] }],
  viewedBy: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", default: [] }],
  suscribers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", default: [] }],
  replies: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment", default: [] }],
});

export default mongoose.models.Thread ||
  mongoose.model<IThread>("Thread", ThreadSchema);
```

I can ignore the error with ts-ignore and everything works fine, but I don't think this is the correct way to go. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead of `Schema.Types.ObjectId` eg. `suscribers: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", default: [] }],`

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar still giving me the same error

Comment: Schema for document please

Comment: @GandalftheWhite can you elaborate?

Comment: Documentexport interface IThread extends Document => Document's schema.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/index.d.ts#L370

Comment: why dont you try ```$set``` instead of ```$addToSet```

Comment: @xetryDcoder I want to ensure uniqueness between elements in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suscribeToThread function:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

suscribeToThread: async (threadId: IThread["_id"], userId: IUser["_id"]) => {
        return await threadModel.updateOne(
          { _id: threadId },
          { $addToSet: { suscribers: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) } }
        );
    }
```

thread model:

```
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from "mongoose";
import { IComment } from "../comment/commentModel";
import { IUser } from "../user/userModel";

export interface IThread extends Document {
    _id: string;
    title: string;
    timestamp: number;
    author: IUser["_id"];
    content: string;
    locked: boolean;
    sticky: boolean;
    likedBy: Array<IUser["_id"]>;
    dislikedBy: Array<IUser["_id"]>;
    viewedBy: Array<IUser["_id"]>;
    suscribers: Array<IUser["_id"]>;
    replies: Array<IComment["_id"]>;
}

const ThreadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    content: String,
    locked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    sticky: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    likedBy: {
        type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: "User",
        default: []
    },
    dislikedBy: {
        type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: "User",
        default: []
    },
    viewedBy: {
        type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: "User",
        default: []
    },
    suscribers: {
        type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: "User",
        default: []
    },
    replies: {
        type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: "User",
        default: []
    }
});

export default mongoose.models.Thread || mongoose.model < IThread > ("Thread", ThreadSchema);
```

You need to convert userId into ObjectId. It is of type string, so typescript is throwing error.

Comment: I get this error with your solution: (property) suscribers?: string | AddToSetOperators<string[]>
Type '_ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'string | AddToSetOperators<string[]>'.
  Property '$each' is missing in type '_ObjectId' but required in type 'AddToSetOperators<string[]>'

Comment: can you please check that the schema is just like, how it is shown in the answer ?